Is there a basis for $K[\mathbb{Z}]$ over $K[2\mathbb{Z}]$ with no invertible element?
Let $K[G]$ be the group algebra of the infinite cyclic group $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$ over the field $K \cong \mathbb{C}$. Then there exists the subalgebra $K[H]$ of $K[G]$ which is defined by the subgroup $H \cong 2\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $K[H]$ contains only even powers of the generator $g$. There is an obvious basis for $K[G]$ over $K[H]$ which is $\{1,g\}$. By this we mean that any element $x \in K[G]$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\{1,g\}$ with coefficients $\{b_1,b_2\}$ taken from $K[H]$. So there exist $b_1,b_2 \in K[H]$ such that $x=b_1+b_2g$. We demonstrate this.
Expressing $\{x,b_1,b_2\}$ by way of the canonical bases of $K[G]$ and $K[H]$ yields $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\lambda_ng^n=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\mu_ng^{2n}+\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\nu_ng^{2n}g$$ where only finitely many of the $\lambda_n$, $\mu_n$, and $\nu_n$ are nonzero. Now it is easy to select the scalar coefficients $\mu_n$ and $\nu_n$ of $b_1$ and $b_2$ such that this equation holds. We just take $\mu_n=\lambda_{2n}$ and $\nu_n=\lambda_{2n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $\{1,g\}$ is a basis of $K[G]$ over $K[H]$.
In $K[G]$ it can be shown that the invertible elements are exactly $\{\lambda g^n \mid \lambda \in K, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Therefore, the basis $\{1,g\}$, and the bases it suggests which are $\{g^{2k-1},g^{2l}\}$ for all $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$, consist of invertible elements. The question now is whether or not there exist bases of $K[G]$ over $K[H]$ which contain at least one element which is not invertible. That is, can we find a basis $\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ of $K[G]$ over $K[H]$ such that one of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ is not a scalar multiple of a power of $g$?

Of course, take $\{1 + g, g\}$. Remember from linear algebra* how to produce new bases from a given one. Every invertible matrix gives a new one, and my example uses $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.
*well, generalized to free modules
